# Can you combine the raw string modifier R"()" with a string variable?

Tags: string, c++11, string-literals

### Example

For example:

```
string MyString = "Normal\tString";
cout << MyString << endl;
```

produces the following: `"Normal    String"`

---

Appending the *raw string modifier* to the string like so:

```
string MyString = R"(Normal\tString)";
cout << MyString << endl;
```

produces the following: `"Normal\tString"`

---

## The Question

Is there a way to append the *raw string modifier* to a variable containing a string in order to print the raw form of the string contained within the variable?

```
string TestString = "Test\tString";
cout << R(TestString) << endl;
```

So you get: `"Test\tString"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to append the raw string modifier to a variable containing a string in order to print the raw form of the string contained within the variable?

No.

However, you can write a function that substitutes the characters that are defined by escape sequences by an appropriate string, i.e. replace the character `'\t'` by the string `"\\t"`.

Sample program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Performs only one substitution of \t.
// Needs to be updated to do it for all occurrences of \t and
// all other escape sequences that can be found in raw strings.    
std::string toRawString(std::string const& in)
{
   std::string ret = in;
   auto p = ret.find('\t');
   if ( p != ret.npos )
   {
      ret.replace(p, 1, "\\t");
   }

   return ret;
}

int main()
{
   std::string TestString = "Test\tString";
   std::cout << toRawString(TestString) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Test\tString
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is tagged as C++11, in which case rolling your own conversion function is probably the best call.

However, if you have a C++14 compiler, you can use the `std::quoted` stream manipulator:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    string s = "Hello\tWorld!";
    std::cout << std::quoted(s) << std::endl; // Prints "Hello\tWorld!"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Kind of.  This works but it's not a pretty solution:

```
std::string strToInsert = " insert this "
std::string myRawString = R"(
raw string raw string raw string
raw string raw string raw string
)"; myRawString += strToInsert; myRawString += R"(raw string
raw string raw string raw string
)";
```